# SQLの抽出について、どのテーブルをベースにすればいいか悩んでます

Tags: mysql, sql

最近SQLに慣れてきて、いろいろ書けるようにはなってきたんですが、書ければいいじゃ終わりたくない状態になってしまいました。
ベースにするテーブル（from句に書くテーブル）ってどれが正解なんだろうとずっと考え込んでしまっています。
何かアドバイス頂けませんでしょうか

追記
企業テーブルがあり、その企業に紐づく店舗テーブルあります。
さらに、店舗に紐づく案件テーブルがあり、
またさらに、案件に紐づく活動テーブルがあります。
抽出定義（簡略化すると）が
企業名、店舗名、案件名、活動名
企業ベースにしても、店舗ベースにしてもどっちでも抽出することができるのですが、
プログラム的にはとっちの方がよいのだろうと悩んでいました

Comment: 具体的なサンプル等があると回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 具体的に悩んでいる例を、質問文を [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。どこで困ってらっしゃるのかが分かりませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

> ベースにするテーブル（from句に書くテーブル）

使用する項目を含むテーブルおよび結合に必要なテーブルすべてです。

例えば『企業名』と『案件名』が必要ならば、企業テーブルと案件テーブル、そしてこの2つのキーを結合する中間テーブルである店舗テーブルが必要です。
使わないならば活動テーブルを結合する必要はありません。

今回のご質問が、「まず最初にプログラムからベースとなるテーブルを1つ取ってきて、そのレコードごとにループして従属テーブルからキーの合致するレコードを取りたい。その場合、最初にベースとして取得するテーブルは企業テーブルが良いのか」という意図でしたら、
回答は「最初からSQLでテーブルを結合して取ってくるのが良いです。それがリレーショナルデータベースの強みです」となります。

そうではなく「joinする順番は、先頭(ベース？)に企業テーブルと店舗テーブルどちらが良いのか」という意図でしたら、
回答は「企業テーブルです。ただし企業テーブルを使わないならばSQLに含まず、店舗テーブルを先頭にjoinして構いません」となります。

Answer (score 0):

質問者さんの言う「正解」は分かりませんけど、参考になりそうなデータベースの構造が見たいということであれば、サンプルデータベースを探してみてはいかがですか。

例えば、Microsoft の SQL Server の場合ですと AdventureWorks というサンプルデータベースが無償提供されています。サンプルデータベースとしてチュートリアルなどでよく使われていた Northwind, Pub などもまだ入手できるはずです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]